# How to split a self-intersection polygon to multipolygon

Tags: split, 2d, polygon, intersection

I would like to implement a Java method which can split a self-intersection polygon to multipolygon. Is there any API or algorithm to do? Thanks.

The following code uses [JavaGeom API](http://geom-java.sourceforge.net/).

```
/**
 * Split a polygon by its intersection(s)
 * @param polygon
 * @return a list of splitted polygons, return itself if no intersection found.
 */
public List<Polygon2D> splitSelfIntersectionPolygon(Polygon2D polygon){
    List<Polygon2D> multiPolygon = new ArrayList<Polygon2D>();

    Polygon2D splittedPolygon = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < polygon.vertexNumber(); i++){
        //...
        multiPolygon.add(splittedPolygon);
    }

    return multiPolygon;
}
```

Comment: I have implemented by myself. It only can support very simple polygon. The current method is to split polygon's lines by self-intersection point. Then, merger the lines if they can be connected (e.g. the same start point / end point). But failed to process complex polygon (which has many self-intersections). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The overall algorithm might be as follows:

1. Find the points where the edges of original polygon intersect using [Bentley–Ottmann algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm)
2. Split intersecting edges in their crossing points, and convert the original polygon in the graph having vertices in crossing points of degree 4 (or higher degree if more than 2 original edges meet in one point).
3. Сonstruct a [minimal spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) of the graph and apply these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612073/given-a-spanning-tree-and-an-edge-not-on-the-spanning-tree-how-to-form-a-cycle) to form loops in it, which will be the polygons forming multipolygon.